# How to get the original element before item was dropped in it's place in jquery sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to switch the elements places for example.
http://jsfiddle.net/dado_eyad/mKaFe/3/

If I moved `Second row: 1` to the place of `First row: 2` I want the later to take the place of the first one.

How can access `First row: 2` to move it to `Second row: 1` original place?

Comment: Maybe table is not the best object for making it sortable. Why can't you use list with `float: left` style for elements? Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/mKaFe/6/.

Comment: What's the difference? If there's a way to do what I want using a list then I'll use lists.

Comment: okay this is good but it actually moves all elements as I'm dragging. It doesn't switch just two places.